# Why i cant start the JS Websocket?

Tags: javascript, php

I am development a chat but yet be at init.

The PHP Socket appear works fine, but the JavaScript no.

Any port that i choose to put it in JS nots works.

I alrady try 8081,3000,3001,8085, etc, etc,...

Nothing works.

The PHP Socket start fine.

**index.php**

```
<output></output>
<input type="text">

<script src="assets/js/WebSocket.js"></script>
```

**WebSocket.js**

```
const output = document.querySelector("output");
const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {

    if (e.code === "Enter") {

        const port = 8081;
        const host = 'wss://127.0.0.1'; 
        const conn = host + ':' + port;

        const ws = new WebSocket(conn);

        ws.onerror = (e) => {
            console.log('error')
            console.log(e)
        };

        ws.onopen = (e) => {
            console.log('open')
            console.log(input.value)
            conn.send(input.value);
        };

        ws.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log('message')
            console.log(e.data);
            output.value += e.data + "\n";
        };
        
    }
    
})
```

**Socket.php**

```
<?php

   $host = "127.0.0.1";
   $port = 8080;

   $soquet = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
   
   socket_bind($soquet, $host, intVal($port));
   socket_listen($soquet);
   socket_accept($soquet);  
   
?>
```

The execution stop here

const ws = new WebSocket(conn);

With the message

**WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8001/' failed:**

How i solve it?

Edit:

A) i am using https:// and wss:://

B) js and php is at same domain

Comment: wss is for tls enabled I believe - which does not work for 127.0.0.1 - my guess. What does ws:// give you? Also: Are there any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: i already try with ws before but some worg

Comment: $port = 8080;  'wss://127.0.0.1:8001/' failed:

Comment: i dont understand. you what that i change the port? if i to do it,, at th same port of Soquet.php,  when i run the js, it will stop the php

Answer (score 0):

A websocket is not a general TCP socket. Websockets are a special protocol on top of TCP and HTTP/1.1 specifically for browsers.

To connect a browser to PHP like this you will need to implement the Websocket protocol or find an existing package that implements it. There's a lot more to the protocol than a plain socket, so using existing libraries is probably the best path.

Comment: Thank you for ty reply. But, yesterday, i get it. But tody, when i tryed again, it not works else. I what to learn it.

Comment: I ttyed with ratchet: some issue

Comment: If you tried something completely different and that failed, you should open a new stack overflow question and go into the details of what you did. As far as your _current_ question, my answer is the right answer and you should accept it.